# Wordpress - get post based on meta field content

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress plugin. I'm using two different custom post types, **players** and **teams**.

- **Players** has relevant meta fields: First name, last name, and team.
- **Teams** has relevant meta fields of team name.

While editing a specific **team** post, I'm trying to have an array of all the **players** that currently have that **team's** name posted to their meta field for team name. I'm not sure how to do this. Any help or articles would be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The important thing is that you are querying for posts using at least the three criteria of the post type, meta key, and meta value.

For example, let's assume your custom post type is just called "player"  And, each 'player' post has a meta field attached called "player_team"

You could then query for those posts using something like this:

```
$teamname = ""; // the player's team that you're querying for

$myquery = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'player',
    'meta_key' => 'player_team',
    'meta_value' => $teamname,
    'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

Comment: Since this is a secondary query inside the team page, it's recommended to use `WP_Query` or `get_posts` instead of `query_posts` - see [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts#Secondary_Loops)

Comment: Updated answer to reflect this

Comment: +1. Nice one, thanks.  By the way (sorry, I didn't notice this before) - it's probably worth adding a `posts_per_page` parameter of -1, to ensure you get all players back (or noting it, anyway, so the asker's aware of the possibility).

Comment: Thanks!! This helps a lot. I was trying to do this with "get_posts" but couldn't seem to get the parameters right.

Comment: Also my CPT was just called "player" not "players". Your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 68):

Or using `get_posts`:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'player_team',
    'meta_value' => $teamname,
    'post_type' => 'player',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Another equivalent query using `meta_query` instead of `meta_key` and `meta_value`:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'player_team',
            'value' => $teamname
        )
    ),
    'post_type' => 'player',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: If you set `'posts_per_page' => -1` that will retrieve all matching posts, no need for `999999`.

Comment: or set `nopaging => true`.

Comment: @vortexs Thanks for the 'post_status' suggestion!

Comment: @cfx If you know there will be few posts you shouldn't worry. E.g.: Team members in a small business. It never will return hundreds of results :P