# Dropdown select search field not working

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, search, select

I added a drowpdown select field (just "yes" / "no" options) to my search form, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I know I'm missing something...

I have a site where people can post listings, so the search is intended to search a part of the listings. I'm going to put four sections of code below, just so you can see how it works. The last part is what I'm trying to figure out - the search form.

Section One - Displays the field on the "post new listing" page.

```
   <h2><?php echo __('Pets OK'); ?>:</h2>
       <select name="pets_ok_field" class="do_input2">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
       <option value="No">No</option>
       </select>
```

Section Two - Sends the selection through

```
    update_post_meta($pid, "pets_ok_field", trim($_POST['pets_ok_field']));
```

Section Three - Displays the selected field info on the listing (or the way I have it setup doesn't if they don't choose an option)

```
<?php
    $pets_ok_field = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pets_ok_field',true);
    if(!empty($pets_ok_field)):?>
   <li>           
   <h3><?php _e("Pets OK", "ClassifiedTheme");?>:</h3>
   <p><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'pets_ok_field',true); ?></p>
   </li> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Part Four - Search form field...this is what I can't figure out.

```
<?php _e('Pets OK',"ClassifiedTheme"); ?> </b><br />
<?php  NO CLUE - TRIED SEVERAL THINGS - NONE WORK ?>
```

Comment: can you please post the best of the several things you tried so that it could be corrected?

Comment: You probably should have mentioned your working with wordpress. I believe what you are asking is how to I query for post by post_meta values?

Comment: Okay, I'm working with wordpress... PHP is PHP isn't it....   this is the line I've tried for the search field, but aren't I missing the array or something  <?php echo get_post_meta($_GET['pets_ok_field'], __("Select"), "do_input2"); ?>

Comment: I apologize bryjohns for my snappyness. I've seriously been sitting here for two days with no sleep trying to figure this out. Sad thing is... this search function is about as elementary as it gets is it not.

Comment: PHP is PHP but wordpress is a heavy handed framework. If you're talking about php you're usually working with PHP standard library. If you're working with wordpress your working with a really nasty framework and with wordpresses api. It's a big difference in getting your question answered.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're looking for something like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068795/wordpress-get-post-based-on-meta-field-content

Comment: Understood, I'm just peeved at this. I've already rewritten the code for just about everything on the site, yet I can't get a simple yes/no search option to work.

Comment: are you trying to show a yes/no select box for search form?

Comment: I can show the select box on the search form, but the functionality is not working... ie, when I search for listings with "no" selected, it still just returns all of the listings, whether the option on the listing is "yes" or "no"

Comment: Just so I have this straight before I attempt to answer this question, you're tying to create a search page (ie `search.php`) and you want to add an extra variable to your search form (ie Yes / No) which will filter what posts the user sees on the search page?

Comment: Maybe this will help... Here is the page: http://www.urbansheet.com/advanced-search/ See where it says "Pets OK" (and right now it's showing array below it) I need that to show a select box referencing the yes/no option on the listings defined by the "pets_ok_field"

Comment: I can manually put a select box there and give the option fields the value="pets_ok_field" but the functionality doesn't work like that. It needs to render the box via PHP like the fields above it...Location for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($_POST['submit'] =='submit')
      {
    update_post_meta($pid, "pets_ok_field", trim($_POST['pets_ok_field']));
        $pets_ok_field = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pets_ok_field',true);
        if(!empty($pets_ok_field))
    {?>
        <h3><?php _e("Pets OK", "ClassifiedTheme");?>:</h3>
        <p><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'pets_ok_field',true); ?></p>
        <?php }} ?>

   <form name="frm" action="" method="post">
       <h2>Pets OK:</h2>
       <select name="pets_ok_field" class="do_input2">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
       <option value="No">No</option>
       </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"  />
     </form>
Hi Please try this
```