# Filter wordpress post by metavalue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I want display `custom post type ='product'` if it has the `metakey='child'` in wordpress admin section:

I used the following method but no products displaying after that.

```
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'posts_where_statement' );
$where = "AND wp_postmeta.metakey LIKE 'child' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' ";
```

---

```
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product'   // This works just fine
AND wp_postmeta.metakey LIKE 'child' // This doesn't work!
```

Please help me on this one. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress - get post based on meta field content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068795/wordpress-get-post-based-on-meta-field-content)

Comment: try `AND wp_postmeta.metakey LIKE '%child%' `

Answer (score 1):

It should have been like this.

```
 add_filter('posts_where', 'posts_where_statement');

    function posts_where_statement( $where = '' ) {
       $where = "AND wp_postmeta.metakey LIKE 'child' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' ";
       return where;
    }
```